# What are the security risks of using WhatSender tool?

Tags: privacy, whatsapp

WhatSender sends Bulk Whatsapp Messages directly from PC using whatsapp web. 
[How it works](https://www.whatsender.net/how-it-works/)

Can this tool actually access messages and images from other chats?

Comment: It can in theory do everything which you can do through the web interface since it is using this. There is no special limited access in WhatsApp for such tools, i.e. they are not restricted in any way.

Comment: To prevent spreading of fake news and misinformation. Facebook bans accounts for spam who seem to be frequently sending messages faster than average speed of typing. They also use some other parameters to detect automated messages.